# Powermockito: mocking static method

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I am mocking a static method as follows:

```
class A{
    static String methodA(HashMap<String,Boolean> h){
        ...  
        Set<String> keys=h.entrySet();  
    }
}
```

Powermockito code:

```
Powermockito.mockstatic(A.class);  
when(A.methodA(any(HashMap.class)).thenReturn("Hey");
```

Now, when I do not expect a call to methodA to enter the function definiton, but directly return "hey". However, this is not happening. Despite the mock, the call to methodA() enters it, and since I am passing `any(HashMap.class)`, a null value is passed. I get a `NullPointerException`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have following on top of your class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ A.class})
 class ATest {
 ....
}
```

The annotation @RunWith, indicates that PowerMockRunner is to be used for executing the test case. Any class which requires static or private methods to be mocked, goes into @PrepareForTest, in this case : class A .

Comment: In line 3 of your code sample, the class name should likely be ATest.

Comment: @MattLachman, yes you are correct. I am going to edit it, thanks!